# Comportamentos diferente entre Linux e Windows usando threads(pthreads)

Tags: c, thread, pthreads

Estou usando a biblioteca pthreads do linux para experimentar as funcionalidades de threads, o código abaixo imprime 5 mensagens na tela para cada thread, cada thread espera a sua vez para exibir a mensagem controlada usando os semáforos, no Windows funciona perfeitamente, porem no linux as threads não esperam a sua vez, já pesquisei tudo que é canto e não consegui chegar a uma solução para esse problema.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct param{
  int id;
  pthread_mutex_t lock;
  sem_t semaforo;
}valores_t;

void * olamundo(void* args){
  valores_t* p = args;
  sem_post(&p->semaforo);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Ola mundo da thread %d\n", p->id);
  }
  sem_wait(&p->semaforo);
}

sem_t semaforo;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  /* code */

  if(sem_init(&semaforo,0,1)){//valor inicial do semaforo começa por 1
    printf("Erro ao iniciar o semaforo\n");
  }

  valores_t p[2];
  pthread_t threads[2];

    p[0].id = 1;
    p[0].semaforo = semaforo;

    p[1].id = 2;
    p[1].semaforo = semaforo;

  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){//inicia as funcoes das threads
    if(pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, &olamundo, &p[i]) == -1){
      printf("Erro ao inicializar a thread\n");
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if(pthread_join(threads[i], NULL)){
      printf("Erro ao sincronizar a thread\n");
    }
    }
    sem_destroy (&semaforo);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434745/c-11-threads-different-behaviour-on-linux-and-windows

Comment: eu consegui concertar esse problema no outro post que fiz no stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503594/using-parameters-with-threads

Comment: o erro é óbvio (e foi apontado no outro SO): você está invertendo a ordem fas operações sem_wait e sem_post...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acontece que aparentemente é um bug no compilador, para resolver esse problema pra funcionar em ambas as plataformas usa-se um ponteiro nas `struct`, para ter mais detalhes sobre a solução veja essa outra thread no stackoverflow [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503594/using-parameters-with-threads)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct param{
    int id;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    sem_t *semaforo; //Dagan: change to a pointer to a semaphore
}valores_t;

void * olamundo(void* args){
    valores_t* p = args;
    sem_wait(*(&p->semaforo)); //Dagan: use the semaphore pointer
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        printf("Ola mundo da thread %d\n", p->id);
    }
    sem_post(*(&p->semaforo)); //Dagan: use the semaphore pointer
}

sem_t semaforo;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    /* code */

    if(sem_init(&semaforo,0,1)){//valor inicial do semaforo começa por 1
        printf("Erro ao iniciar o semaforo\n");
    }

    valores_t p[2];
    pthread_t threads[2];

    p[0].id = 1;
    p[0].semaforo = &semaforo; //Dagan: pass the address of the semaphore

    p[1].id = 2;
    p[1].semaforo = &semaforo; //Dagan: pass the address of the semaphore

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){//inicia as funcoes das threads
        if(pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, &olamundo, &p[i]) == -1){
            printf("Erro ao inicializar a thread\n");
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if(pthread_join(threads[i], NULL)){
            printf("Erro ao sincronizar a thread\n");
        }
    }
    sem_destroy (&semaforo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: como comentei acima, o erro é a ordem de uso das operações no semáforo...de todo modo, se você tem uma solução que acredite correta deve colocar aqui, e não apontar para uma pergunta no SO em inglês

Comment: acho que vc não entendeu minha pergunta, o código que tenho funciona no linux, pq a ordem dos semáforos fazeria com que não funcionasse no windows? de qualquer maneira tive uma solução e expliquei acima, seria redundante colocar o código com a solução já que está na minha thread original em inglês

Comment: bom, eu trabalho com threads diariamente, e isso já faz muitos anos, acho muito mais provável você não ter sabido explicar do que eu não ter entendido...quanto à "resposta" que você teve, não seria "redundande" colocar aqui, afinal de contas você fez a pergunta aqui...